# how to make input tag(token) same as stackoverflow/gmail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

library = https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

This is my code: I need get all values of input, I used `$("input").val()` but `return =""` always.
[input tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYwjd.png) [image]

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"> </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <input type="text" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this jquery library. [bootstrap-tokenfield](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/)

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="tokenfield" value="red,green,blue" />
```

**Jquery :**

```
$('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
  autocomplete: {
    source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
    delay: 100
  },
  showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
})
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rns3hang/2/)

Comment: @HansLeoQuirozMarroquin great to hear that mate :) *Happy Coding*

Answer (score 0):

With this lab, you can call an array with all values:

```
$("input").tagsinput('items')
```

Like that (open your terminal and check the console.log): https://jsfiddle.net/DiogoBernardelli/bzyphmuu/

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/mithunjohn/fu57os8s/1/), I was able to print output in console,

```
console.log($("input").val())
```